# Wrong rendering for textfield using styled markup

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio v. 6.17.0. I have a textfield that displays product order info and, on a second line, displays associated notes in bold. See for example [image]

The textfield expression to do this is
`$F{vendorPartNum} + ($F{isPoItemNote} ? "\n" + "<style isBold='true'>" + $F{poItemNote} + "</style>" : "")`. The field values for the above screenshot are [image]

This has been working for a long time. Recently, for one case, it hasn't. For this input,

[image]

the rendering is

[image]

Here, the HTML tags for formatting are being rendered literally instead of being used for formatting. What's wrong?

=====

Here's the textfield definition.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="31"/>
    <box padding="5">
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vendorPartNum} + ($F{isPoItemNote} ? "\n" + "<style isBold='true'>" + $F{poItemNote} + "</style>" : "")]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```